# XCode: copy bundle resources on build

Tags: xcode4.5

In xCode I can add resources (folders, documents) to "Copy Bundle Resources phase". The first time, the resources gets deployed correctly. But after that each time, they don't get updated. I have to clean and rebuild again. Did I miss some important setting? This is especially annoying if you deploy JS files and changed the code in them. The simulator will still run the old JS code.

Comment: How did you manage to get the files copied? I cannot achieve that. I'm in Xcode 4.5